# inappropriate behaviour on bootstrap tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a issue with tabs on Bootstrap:

I coded a page that's is suppose to be full width/height and the navbar would be the tabs.
I don't know why when I click on any tab button, It brings me a weird transition that isn't supposed to be there.

**I just need a static tab menu, out off any transitions**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Daniel</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="navarea transition-width">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
              LOGO
              </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Tab5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

    <div class="tab-content text-center">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>TAB 1</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">

        <div class="tab-content text-center">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h1>TAB 2</h1>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        <div class="tab-content text-center">
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <h1>TAB 3</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>TAB 4</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>TAB 5</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

> Is better if you check out the snippet by full screen;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of fluff in here that you probably don't need, but I removed one of the

```
data-target="#navbarCollapse"
```

and it stopped animating

Found this example on w3schools that you could probably check out as well:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Daniel</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="navarea transition-width">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
              LOGO
              </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Tab5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

    <div class="tab-content text-center">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>TAB 1</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">

        <div class="tab-content text-center">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h1>TAB 2</h1>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        <div class="tab-content text-center">
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <h1>TAB 3</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>TAB 4</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>TAB 5</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That was a nice solution, thanks my friend!!
About the unnecessary stuff, I made my code simple just for your interpretation but definitely the problem was `data-target="#navbarCollapse"`